# Branch.io React Native track ad campaign information

Tags: facebook, react-native, branch.io

In my react native app, I have the branch.io & Facebook sdk integrated. I can see the number of installs in the branch dashboard.

I want to save the information to my db as well. Like I want to know which user, in particular, came from which Ad campaign. The documentation does not seem to give a clear indication of how to do that.

Please note that Branch Universal links work just fine. I can extract data from the link. Your help would be required for the case where I cannot put universal links like Facebook Ads.

Comment: Did you manage to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Understanding your query here, I can understand that you are looking to fetch user data with respect to the campaign and ad level data from Facebook.

Facebook does not allow sharing of device-level information unless you sign the 'Advanced Mobile Measurement' agreement for Facebook. Once signed, you can get the data out to your internal database via Webhooks, the Daily Export API, and CSV Exports.
We cannot send device-level Facebook attribution data to third parties. Please instead consider analyzing this data in-house.

You can check on the link here for a better understanding : https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-faq-and-advanced-options#section-can-i-get-the-data-out

Hope the above helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also want to extract data if user is opening(not installing) my app through facebook ad link.

My app has two domains verified through play console and aslo mentioned in manifest.xml file so if any user is coming through links which have any of those domain i am able to capture those links but if any user is opening my app through facebook ad link(not installing) then i am unable to capture those link.
So what my problem is if the user coming through verified links then on click on those links my app directly opens and i can capture the link but if i click on facebook ad link it will take the user to play store page of app then user can open the app from there so my app is not directly launching  because of that i am unable to capture the link.

So my concern is that can i also verify play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my-app-package-name this host and does my app launch directly ?

Because if my app is launched directly through a link i can capture it using Linking.getInitialUrl()

Comment: Answers should not be used to ask for clarification. Once you'll earn enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you'll be able to [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).